# Selecting :visible table cell with jquery does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, visibility

I have a table which automatically hides columns on smaller screens. On some columns the header is spanning two rows like so:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" class="essential">Bestellung</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Nummer</th>
       <th>Datum</th>
       <th class="essential">Menge</th>
       <th class="essential">Wert</th>
   </tr>  
 </thead>
 ...
```

I have some logic so the user can hide/show the columns he wants. I use this to make sure that if all columns in the second header row are hidden, the corresponding element in the first header row also hides and of course the other way around = show the first row element as soon as one second row element is toggled.

```
var doubles = thead.find( "tr:first-child th, TR:first-child TH" ).not('[rowspan=2]');
if ( thead.find("tr, TR").length > 1 && thead.find("tr:last-child th:visible, TR:last-child TH:visible" ).length === 0 ) {
    doubles.hide();
    } else {
       doubles.show();
       }
```

The **:visible** selector works ok on larger screen sizes. On smaller size, I auto-hide some columns on load and then the selector does not work anymore.

In the above example the .essential classes are visible. Yet when I toggle any of the classes the following always returns 0: I don't understand why the console says 0,0,0 although 1,2,3 or all 4 elements are visible.

Maybe someone can point me to the possible cause.

```
 console.log( thead.find("tr:last-child th:visible").length );
 console.log( thead.find("tr:last-child th").filter(":visible").length );
 console.log( thead.find("tr:last-child th[display=table-cell]").length );
```

is there another way to select visible elements?

Comment: It appears to have been a bug in older versions of jQuery: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4512.  Is your jQUery version current?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead:

```
$.expr[":"].displayed = function(e) { //Custom pseudo:
   return e && $(e).css("display") !== "none";
};
$(function() { //On DOMReady
    var thead = $("thead");
    doubles = thead.find("tr:first-child th, tr:first-child th").not("[rowspan=2]");
    if (thead.find("tr, TR").length > 1 && thead.find("tr:last-child th:displayed, tr:last-child th:displayed").length === 0) {
        doubles.hide();
    } else {
        doubles.show();
    }
});​
```

Note that the latest version of Sizzle doesn't have `:visible`. See a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vNUSJ/).